# Owncloud 6 and Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, owncloud, ubuntu-14.04

I would configure my home pc for Owncloud 6 using Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04.

When I go to `https://localhost/owncloud/` or `https://localhost/` I obtain only a "502 - Bad Gateway" error.

These are the configuration files that I use.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 2;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/owncloud**

```
upstream php-handler {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name localhost;

    ssl_certificate /usr/share/nginx/ssl/myssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /usr/share/nginx/ssl/myssl.key;

    root /usr/share/nginx/www/owncloud/;

    client_max_body_size 10G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    rewrite ^/caldav(.*)$ /remote.php/caldav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/carddav(.*)$ /remote.php/carddav$1 redirect;
    rewrite ^/webdav(.*)$ /remote.php/webdav$1 redirect;

    index index.php;
    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location ~ ^/(data|config|\.ht|db_structure\.xml|README) {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json last;

        rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ redirect;
        rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ redirect;

        rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;

        try_files $uri $uri/ index.php;
    }

    location ~ ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)?$ {
        try_files $1 = 404;

        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$1;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $2;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
        fastcgi_pass php-handler;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|css|js|swf)$ {
        expires 30d;
        access_log off;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is you php server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000?

Answer (score 0):

Check your www.conf for user = www-data group = www-data
Then sudo service nginx restart 
Then sudo service php-fpm restart